# Sorting string data in "ddmmyy" format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have few string with data as

```
  var stringData = new List<string> {"31/01/17 09:15:09",
                                            "1/02/17 09:15:09",
                                            "3/02/17 09:15:09",
                                            "4/02/17 09:15:09",
                                            "30/01/17 09:15:09",
                                            "8/01/17 09:15:09"};

        var orderedData = stringData.OrderBy(a => a);
        var orderedData1 = stringData.OrderByDescending(a => a);
```

Is there any way using which we can get the data in the correct sorted order?

Comment: I will never understand what's the point on working with datetimes as strings...

Comment: This data is going to be displayed in the JSON format, and it hast to be in the "ddmmyy" format and not "ddmmyyyy"

Comment: Because often that's the way they're passed between systems, e.g. in XML, JSON, CSV, etc.

Comment: Well, then order them, do all the job, as DateTimes and just convert them to strings when you are going to pass them as JSON

Answer (score 4):

```
var orderedList = stringData.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
ParseExact will allow you to specify the exact format of your date string to use for parsing.

```
var orderedList = stringData.OrderByDescending(
                x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "d/MM/yy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

Comment: DateTime.Parse(x) throws 'System.FormatException' exception

Comment: I think you should use `ParseExact` with `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` format

Comment: @m.rogalski should be `"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: The year format has to be YY as per my requirement .

Comment: @Pikoh Yes, my bad haven't paying attention on the year :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var sortedList = stringData.OrderByDescending(
                x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "d/MM/yy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();

foreach (var item in sortedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This should give the expected output.

Explanation :

As per the values provided in the list its clear that Date part comes first, then month and then year. Also date is possibly of one digit and year is only two digits and all the values have month with two digits.

So for Date, format `d/MM/yy` makes sense for the date part.

The time part in all the value are less then 12 and minutes and seconds part are self explanatory. Also the time part does not have any information about AM or PM.

So for Time, format `hh:mm:ss` is suitable.

Combining Formats of date and time with space in between would parse the value correctly as the values in the list have date and time part separated by space.

So the final format is `d/MM/yy hh:mm:ss`.

We won't need to provide any specific format provider or cultureinfo here as the format of the datetime strings can be determined easily.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation? It would be good for the newcomers to read detailed answer. I'm asking because it's the best answer yet and it should be explained :

Comment: Done. Feel free to provide inputs if any more changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use DateTime.Parse on each of the List elements, and then use the ToString of the DateTime struct to format your date into what you need.

This is an example of how to use the Parse function:

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse(stringData[0]);
```

This is how to use the ToString to format it:

```
string result=t1.ToString("dd/mm/yy");
```

And now to combine everything together will be something like this:

```
var formattedStrings=stringData.Select(DateTime.Parse).Select(x => x.ToString("dd/mm/yy")).OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

(example of the concept, not a way to use it)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to make your scenario works.

First one You can parse string value to `DateTime` with [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method to new collection or (the other one option) only for sorting:

```
List<string> result = stringData
        .OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "d/MM/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .ToList();

List<DateTime> dateTimeResult = stringData.
        .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "d/MM/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .ToList();
```

I highly recommend to use second one and works with `DateTime` objects instead of `string` because you may need to work with ordered values as a dates and it'll be worse to convert them each time only for using [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but here is lazy way without parsing:

```
var ordered = (from s in stringData
               let a = s.Split('/', ' ')
               where a.Length > 2
               orderby a[2], a[1], a[0]
               select a[0].PadLeft(2, '0') + '/' + a[1].PadLeft(2, '0')
               + '/' + a[2].Substring(a[2].Length - 2)).ToList();
```